# To limit the number of pages shown in pagination

Tags: php, pagination

```
  <?php

  global $con;

  $get_mov = "SELECT * FROM movies";
  $run_mov = mysqli_query($con, $get_mov); 

  $number_of_movies = mysqli_num_rows($run_mov);

  $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_movies/4);

  if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = 1;
  }
  else {
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  }   

 $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*4;

 $get_mov = "SELECT * FROM movies order by movie_released DESC  LIMIT "  . 
 $this_page_first_result.  ',' . 4;

 $run_mov = mysqli_query($con, $get_mov);

 while ($row_mov = mysqli_fetch_array($run_mov)) {
  $mov_id = $row_mov['movie_id']; 
  $mov_desc = $row_mov['movie_desc'];
  $mov_title = $row_mov['movie_title'];
  $mov_cat = $row_mov['movie_cat'];

  echo " 

    <article id ='post-8045' class='article'>

                    <h4><a href='single.php?mov_id=$mov_id' style='text- 
   decoration:none'>$mov_title</a></h4>
                    <p>$mov_desc</p>

                </article>


   ";
   }
   ?>
                <nav class="float-right">



                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="? 
  page=<?php $pagep = $page-1; echo $pagep; ?>" aria-label="Previous"><span 
  aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li>

                      <?php
                       for($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) { 
                        echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='index.php? 
   page=$page' class='page-link' style='text- 
   decoration:none;color:black;'>$page</a></li>"; 
                             }
                     ?>

                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="? 
   page=<?php $pagen = $page+1; echo $pagen; ?>" aria-label="Next"><span 
   aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

This is my code...I have too many pages to be shown so they are making a long line like..1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 and so on. Moreover the next button query is also not working...
I want to limit those as << 4 5 6 7 8 9 >> ...instead of that...
I Searched the whole web and youtube and contacted all peers i know..but found nothing...
More info:
"movies" is my database name.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Share your code... We're not here to write free code for you. Here's how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide some detail in your question. Show us how you create the paging in the first place, what have you tried to solve your problem, be very specific, better chance of help.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you want to limit the number of page links in your pagination. First of all, you need to formulate your requirement, in your question you only say "I want to limit those as << 4 5 6 7 8 9 >>" which is not a sufficient specification to work with. So let's try with this specification:

- We want a maximum of 6 page links
- When we are on the first and second page, the links should be << 1 2 3 4 5 6 >>
- When we are on page k, the links should be << k-2 k-1 k k+1 k+2 k+3 >>
- Unless k<3, where we want to start with 1
- Unless k>n-3, with n the total number of pages, then we want << n-5 n-4 n-3 n-2 n-1 n >>

So now we have to find an algorithm that's simple enough, yet fulfils all those requirements. One way to do this would be

```
$start = max(min($k-2, $n-5), 1);
$end = min($start+5, $n);
```

Full code  with test:

```
function print_pagination($n, $k)
{
  printf("%d pages, we are on %d:\n", $n, $k);
  $start = max(min($k-2, $n-5), 1);
  $end = min($start+5, $n);
  for ($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++) {
    if ($i==$k)
      printf('%d ', $i);
    else
      printf('<a href="...">%d</a> ', $i);
  }
  echo("\n");
}

print_pagination(10, 1);
print_pagination(10, 3);
print_pagination(10, 6);
print_pagination(10, 10);

print_pagination(3, 1);
print_pagination(3, 2);
print_pagination(3, 3);
```

Comment: thank you so much karsten..You don't know you helped me alot..i never repay this..Again thank you for this..if you were in front of me..i would definitely hug you